# Google Analytics beacon sent but Analytics shows nothing

Tags: google-analytics

I installed Google Analytics (UA) and added tracking code to a html page. 
I ran html page from the browser file:///C:/test.html and debugged using google debugger, it ran successfully and shows sent beacon - but Analytics does not show the numbers. I waited for a day but still does not work.

**It works fine if I place the file in c:\Inetpub\wwwwroot and run as http://localhost/test.html
-------------------Code in test.html page-------

```
  <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)
      {i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
          (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
              m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
      ga('create', 'UA-******-*', 'auto',{'storage': 'none'});
      ga('set', 'checkProtocolTask', null);
      ga('send', 'pageview');
  </script>
```

Can anyone tell me if google analytics works in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do should definitely work, but you'll have to modify a few other things you're sending to prevent the hit from being dropped by Google Analytics.

Basically what's happening now is your [hit is invalid](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/?v=1&t=pageview&tid=UA-12345-1&cid=856505171.1457306597&_v=j41d&a=1402878201&_s=1&dl=file%3A%2F%2F%2FC%3A%2Ftest.html&ul=en-us&sd=24-bit&sr=1440x900&vp=1440x297&je=0&fl=20.0%20r0&_u=QEAAAIAB~&z=1504461516). As you can see here using the [Hit Builder tool](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/?v=1&t=pageview&tid=UA-12345-1&cid=856505171.1457306597&_v=j41d&a=1402878201&_s=1&dl=file%3A%2F%2F%2FC%3A%2Ftest.html&ul=en-us&sd=24-bit&sr=1440x900&vp=1440x297&je=0&fl=20.0%20r0&_u=QEAAAIAB~&z=1504461516).

I think you should be able to get around this by using the [`page`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#page) field instead of the [`location`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#location) field (which is auto-populated by analytics.js when you create the tracker), like so:

```
ga('set', 'location', null);
ga('set', 'page', '/test.html');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

I've never tried this without also setting the `location` field, so it's possible Google Analytics will still complain that no hostname is present (Note: I tested this with [Google Tag Assistant](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/tag-assistant/) and it did complain, but it didn't say anything about the hit being invalid, so it will probably work fine.)

If using `page` instead of `location` doesn't work, you can always just modify `location` and give it a fake hostname, and that will definitely work.

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  var oldLocation = tracker.get('location');
  var newLocation = oldLocation.replace('file:///C:', 'http://fakehostname.com');

  tracker.set('location', newLocation);
})

ga('send', 'pageview');
```

In either case, you won't need to unset the `checkProtocolTask` because you're now not using the `file` protocol.

Since it sounds like hostname doesn't matter in your case, giving it a fake value should have no impact on your reports.